# Extract a BoundField to a Label

Tags: asp.net, webforms, data-access-layer, detailsview

I have a DetailsView which works fine using a data access layer and a query string.  However, I'd like to extract one of the fields and use it as the text in a label to go above the DetailsView as a title to that page.

Is this possible? And if so, how?

This is an abstract of the DetailsView:

```
<Fields>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="bandname" HeaderText="Band" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="contactname" HeaderText="Contact" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="county" HeaderText="County" />
</Fields>
```

and the code behind:

```
if (Request.QueryString.Count != 0)
{
    int id = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["bandid"]);
    dtvBand.Visible = true;
    List<Band> bandDetails = new List<Band> { BandDAL.AnonGetAllBandDetails(id) };

    dtvBand.DataSource = bandDetails;
    dtvBand.DataBind();
}
```

What I'd like to do is take the data in the first BoundField row and make it the text of a label. Pseudocode:

```
Label1.Text = (<asp:BoundField DataField="band")
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not try to find the text on the `DetailsView` but in it's `DataSource`. You could use the `DataBound` event which is triggered *after* the `DetailsView` was databound, so it's ensured that the `DataItem` exists.

It depends on the `Datasource` of your `DetailsView`. Often it is  a `DataRowView`. You have to cast it, then you can access it's column:

```
protected void DetailsView1_DataBound(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DetailsView dv = (DetailsView)sender;
    string yourText = (string)((DataRowView)dv.DataItem)["ColumnName"];
    Label1.Text = yourText;
}
```

If it's not a `DataRowView` use the debugger to see what `dv.DataItem` actually is.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve what I wanted using:

```
string titletext = dtvBand.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
            dtvBand.Rows[0].Visible = false;
            lblBand.Text = titletext;
```

It takes the first row of the DetailsView, puts it above the rest in a Label so it can be formatted as a header, then hides the first row of the DetailsView.

Comment: This approach fails if someone changes the DetailsView, for example uses a TemplateField to use a control.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a TemplateField as what Tim mentioned:

```
<Fields>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Band") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Fields>
```